# Browser test fails on travis CI / sauce labs

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, travis-ci, saucelabs

I have a simple browser test which runs and passes locally:

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';
import path from 'path';

const By = webdriver.By;
const until = webdriver.until;

const chromeDriverPathAddition = `:${path.dirname(require('chromedriver').path)}`;
process.env.PATH += chromeDriverPathAddition;
const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build();

afterEach(() => {
  driver.quit();
});

describe('App', () => {
  it('page is loaded', async () => {
    driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
    driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
    driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
    const results = await driver.findElement(By.id('search')).getAttribute('innerHTML');

    expect(results.indexOf('webdriver')).to.be.above(0);
  });
});
```

My npm test command is:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha ./test/**/*.browser.js --compilers js:babel-core/register --require babel-polyfill --timeout 60000"
}
```

I am getting a connection to sauce connect buy my test having time out:
https://travis-ci.org/yanivefraim/tdd-tutorial

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you look at the Selenium log on Sauce Lab's side, how far does your test execute. (You should be able to easily deduce what line of JavaScript code corresponds to what line in the log.)

Comment: it executes for the timeout I added - 60000 ms